# How can I do something only for the first function call?

Tags: php, arrays, function, logic

I am losing data from array with the code below:

```
private function addIndexKey($parent) {
$myKeys = array();
foreach ($parent->children as $child) {
    $pos = $child->varGet('flow_pos');
    if (!isset($pos))
        $pos = $child->position;
    if (isset($child->index))
        $myKeys["$pos"] = $child->index;
    if (isset($child->children) && count($child->children)>0) {
        $subkeys = $this->addIndexKey($child);
        if (count($subkeys)>0)
            $myKeys["$pos"] = $subkeys;
    }
}
ksort($myKeys);
return $myKeys;
}
```

I am looping through an array of arrays, which sometimes losses data when I return the `$myKeys` array.

I am assuming its because of redefining the `$myKeys` array when the same function is called again in the third condition. I want the first line of the function to execute only once when the function is called for the first time.

Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: I have been trying to solve this problem for long but haven't succeeded yet. If i make it static i get the values but as it loops through for huge number of time i get really huge array which is mostly empy. Is there any way i can remove all the empty indexes and keep only those which have values?

Comment: Use `array_filter()` to get rid off empty values, e.g. `$myKeys = array_filter($myKeys);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can archive this with different ways. I will just show a few here:

1. Static variable

   Make your array static, so the initialization is only done on the first function call, e.g.

   ```
   function addIndexKey($parent) {
   static $myKeys = array();  //Will only be initialized once
   //...
   }
   ```
2. Optional argument

   Make your argument optional and don't pass an array on the first function call, e.g.

   ```
   function addIndexKey($parent, $myKeys  = []) {
   //Now call the function like this: addIndexKey($parent, $myKeys)
   }
   addIndexKey($parent)//First call without the optional argument, which means it gets initialized
   ```
3. (Class property)

   Since you have a visibility for your function I assume that you are in a class, which means you could use `$myKeys` as a class property, which you can initialize with an empty array, e.g.

   ```
   class XY {
     protected $myKeys = [];

     private function addIndexKey($parent) {
         //Use '$this->myKeys' here
     }     
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
$count = 0;
private function addIndexKey($parent) {
global $count;
if(count == 0)
    $myKeys = array();
$count++
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable to false when your function runs for the first time, and inside your function check if that is true, then run your first line.

```
$isFirstTime = true;

function Your_function_name(){
global $isFirstTime;
if ($isFirstTime){
//Run some code 
}

$isFirstTime = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if $myKeys has already been created or if it is an array, depending of the actions you perform earlier on your code, at the first line of your function .

```
if( !is_array($myKeys) )$myKeys = array();
 //OR EITHER
if( !isset($myKeys) )$myKeys = array();
```